# Convergence of $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt {15+ x^{\alpha}}-\sqrt {x^{\alpha}}}{(3+(1+x)^{1/2})^{1/2}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I want to obtain for which $\alpha\in \Bbb R$ the integral $$\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt {15+ x^{\alpha}}-\sqrt {x^{\alpha}}}{(3+(1+x)^{1/2})^{1/2}}dx$$ is convergent.

My answer: Let be $f(x)= \dfrac{\sqrt {15+ x^{\alpha}}-\sqrt {x^{\alpha}}}{(3+(1+x)^{1/2})^{1/2}}$, then for $\alpha >0$ $$f(x)\rightarrow      C\frac{1}{x^{1/4+\alpha/2}}$$for $x\rightarrow \infty $, and therefore the integral converges for $\alpha >3/2$. For $\alpha \le 3/2$ it can be shown in the same way the integral diverges. is it right ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use difference of squares

$$\sqrt{15+x^\alpha}-\sqrt{x^\alpha} = \frac{15}{\sqrt{15+x^\alpha}+\sqrt{x^\alpha}}$$

to justify your comparisons for both small and large $x$ (be careful you are not making the same assumptions for both).

Comment: For small $x$ the integrand is patently finite; it's only the limit as $x\to\infty$ that affects convergence.

Comment: Yes i do. I think that my answer Is tight or not ?